# When should I consider to add more RAM to VPS instead of CPU?

Tags: vps, memory-usage, cpu-usage

I have a VPS hosting a Wordpress site. When the traffic is too high, I usually see the CPUs are very busy and fully occupied.

Therefore, I always try to add more CPU cores to the VPS. For example, 4 CPUs + 1GB RAM.

I often see only 30%-40% RAM is used for my different VPS setups and the SWAPs are rarely used (maybe 5%-10% of SWAP allocated). It seems RAM is never a issue but CPU. However I am wondering in what case increasing RAM should be considered?

Comment: When you run out of RAM. Of course. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you do not saturate your RAM, then it is not necessary to add it.

However, consider that additional RAM should improve your i/o speed by virtue of disk caching.

So, if your workload is read-mostly and you are suffering of high CPU iowait time, adding more RAM can be useful.

Comment: Is the disk caching you referred to managed by OS itself or it's something I have to configure?

Comment: The OS itself uses RAM for disk caching.

Comment: Just use SSDs ;)

Comment: SSDs are nice, but still aren't quite as good as RAM.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a means to console into the server you should do so during a high load time and see what processes are hogging the most CPU usage. You may discover that you can disable or modify certain protocols to lower overhead.

As stated in the other answer, if your RAM usage is not peaking and your CPU is, than your CPU is the bottleneck.